# jQuery Validate plugin and HTML5 Placeholder plugin issues with IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, placeholder

I am having an issue with the Jquery validate and html5 placeholder. It works great in chrome and FF but IE 9 and below I have an issue. I only see the issue when I hit submit first.

Every field  that is required and has the placeholder text wont disappear when typing into the text field

http://screencast.com/t/R0hqbXKm

Here is my code in the header

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

//Start code

// end code

// Updated

    $('#form339').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            firstName: {
                required: true
            },
            lastName: {
                required: true
            },
            Company: {
                required: true
            },
            EmailAddress: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        }
    });

});

</script>

<script src="/js/microsite/html5placeholder.jquery.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $(':input[placeholder]').placeholder();
    });
</script>
```

---

Code in body

```
<fm action="#" method="post" name="f1">
    <input name="elqFormName" type="hidden" value="####" />
    <input name="elqSiteId" type="hidden" value="1363" />
    <input name="elqCampaignId" type="hidden" />
    <input name="sfdc_campaign" type="hidden" value="701D0000000auNz" />
    <input name="lead_request" type="hidden" value="000" />
    <input name="lead_source" type="hidden" value="2013-Rebrand" />
    <input name="Salutation1" placeholder="*Prefix" type="text" />
    <input name="firstName" placeholder="*First Name" type="text" />
    <input name="lastName" placeholder="*Last Name" type="text" />
    <input name="EmailAddress" placeholder="*Email Address" type="text" />
    <input name="Company" placeholder="*Company" type="text" />
    <input name="HQ_State1" placeholder="HQ State/Province" type="text" />
    <!--<input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone">-->
    <br />
    <select class="drop1" name="country">
          <option selected="selected" value="">Country</option>
          <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
          <option value="United States">United States</option>
          <option value="CA">CA</option></select>
          <!--<div class="requiredtxt">* Required fields</div>-->
    <input alt="SUBMIT!" border="0" class="submit_style" height="29" src="/images/general/Submit2.png" type="image" width="252" />
    &nbsp;
</form>
```

How can I fix this issue

Comment: In the future, please post your HTML in a format we can easily read.  One long string without line-breaks is unacceptable.

Comment: Since your problem is likely more to do with `.placeholder()`, please include information about this plugin.

Comment: What is `<fm ...` supposed to be?  Did you mean `<form ...`?  You've also attached `.validate()` to `$('#form339')`, but there is no `id="form339"` anywhere in your HTML.  Please fix your OP so we can help.

Answer (score -1):

You have extra commas in your javascript objects.

```
firstName: {
    required: true,  // <--- remove comma
},
```

Comment: Which is fine for any browser other than IE.

Comment: Updated to this

$('#form339').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            rules: {
            firstName: {
                required: true
                },
             lastName: {
                required: true
                },
            Company: {
                required: true
                },
             EmailAddress: {
                 required: true,
                 email: true
            }
            }
    });

    });

Comment: extra comma issue was fixed in IE8 but still better to remove it

Comment: Downvoted even though this causes errors in IE6/7? *facepalm*

Comment: I'm not sure this deserves a down-vote, but since the OP is also having problems in IE 8 & 9, this cannot be the solution to his problem.

Comment: @Sparky There is not enough code supplied to solve all the issues. And in IE7, this is the cause of *an* issue.